# Argument in reference

Tags: javascript

I have an object:

```
obj = {
    obj1: {
        name: "Test";
    }
}
```

and function:

```
var anon = function(a) {
    alert(obj.a.name);
}
```

I want to give as an argument "obj1". Im newbie to programming so I think I should get alert with "Test" but it doesn't work. How to give reference with argument?

Comment: Must mention that argument "obj1" must be string !

Answer (score 4):

You can do this way: You can always access properties of the object as `obj[key]`, thats what we are doing here.

```
var anon = function(a) {
    alert(obj[a].name);
}
```

and remove `;` from the inline object property definision syntax.

```
obj = {
    obj1: {
        name: "Test"; //<-- Here
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RuCnU/

This [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) can provide you some basic insight on object and keys.

Answer (score 1):

```
var anon = function(a) {
    alert(obj[a].name);
}
```

When you are looking up the property of an object using a string use square brackets, the `obj.a` will only work if the object has a property named `a`, for example `obj = {a: "Test"}`.